# MySQL and Entity Framework VS 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework

I have problem with create connection with my database in Visual Studio 2017. My steps:

- Run Xampp apache and mysql.
- Create new project in VS (C# WPF).
- Add to my project NuGet packet "MySql.Data.Entity" v6.10.8.

After that I have references:

```
MySql.data ; 
MySql.data.entity.EF6 ;
Mysql.data.entityframwework.
```

- Try to add new data model "ADO.NET entity data model" and I have not MySQL database to choice.

https://ibb.co/PcCYFrF

https://ibb.co/FbmxMYs

Comment: Does your machine have a usable MySQL driver? EF6 isn't a database driver/connector - EF6 is of course needed to create a set of objects backed by a MySQL data store, but the grunt work of connecting to the db, shuttling data back and forth etc is handled by the database driver. That you can't create a MySQL connection leads me to believe your machine doesn't have MySQL connector

Comment: I installed MySql Connector/Net (mysql-connector-net-8.0.13.msi) before creating project in VS.

Comment: As a test, create a file called A.UDL on your desktop and doubl click it. You'll see the standard data sources setup dialog; configure it so a test connection to your MySQL succeeds, then open the a.udl file in a text editor; it will contain your connection string

Comment: It looks like you have not included the connection string. Probably, it is a good idea to follow a tutorial about MySQL for C#.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I create UDL file and i have something like this: [link](https://ibb.co/cQQP0jS). I cant select MySql in provider card.